# How to parse 16 Gb XML file using python always pop up memory error?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, memory, tags

I would like to know How to parse 16 Gb XML file using python since it is always pop up memory error?

```
import numpy as np
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import datetime

tree = ET.parse('M.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
root.tag
newsitems = []
```

Comment: Each XML entity is expressed as a larger python object. You could try `lxml` or something like `libxml2` for a more efficient storage of the DOM. Or perhaps SAX or iterative parser to scrape your data while never holding the full data set in memory. There are other options too, like paring down an XML document with XSLT stylesheets (works for some things, not others). Or perhaps an XML database. In the end, that's a huge amount of data for a technology like an XML DOM that is intended to be held all at once in memory.

Comment: Start by researching similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxml%5D+%5Bpython%5D+large+file

Comment: Best way of parsing huge xml is to use XmlReader which is available in both Powershell and c# and does not get out of memory exception.

Comment: There are plenty of technologies that will do a streaming parse of a large XML without building a tree in memory. Which of them is appropriate to your needs depends on what you want to do with the data after parsing it.

Comment: Etree supports `iterparse` to iteratively parse XML without holding entire document in memory. And since v1.5, even pandas [read_xml](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) supports iterparse for etree and lxml parsers intended for large XML. As [IO docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-read-xml) explain, the method can parse Wikipedia's 12 GB XML dump and as background did so in 5 mins on a machine with 8 GB RAM!

Answer (score 0):

For such a case use the [Pull API for non-blocking parsing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). You can feed parts of your XML to the **XMLPullParser**:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

parser = ET.XMLPullParser(['start', 'end']) # other  events are comment, pi, start-ns, end-ns

with open("M.xml", 'r') as f_xml:
    for line in f_xml:
        parser.feed(line)

for event, elem in parser.read_events():
    print(event)
    print(elem.tag, 'text=', elem.text)
```